# I have a crazy virus

Tags: virus

I have a message pop up when I log in and try to open a folder with my go pro footage. It pops up a window with the title being "you are about to be logged off" and the window text "a virus was detected, your PC will be destroyed in a few seconds" then it restarts. I have tried logging into safe mode and running malewarebytes with no success. Any suggestions??

Comment: screenshots would be nice

Comment: Haven't used it so I can't vouch for it, but perhaps it will help: https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v69675421_EndUserProfile_en_us?OpenDocument&src=smr2011 .

Comment: This sounds more like a prank, than big time cybercrime malware. Does anyone else have access to your computer, that may be trying to play a prank like this on you?

Comment: "your PC will be destroyed in a few seconds?". Haha. It might not be a virus at all (if you have geeky friends who'd play a joke like this on you). However, if it is, then logging into Safe Mode and doing a scan should help. Could you edit your question to add more details? (screenshots, scan logs, [a list of startup entries](http://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/autoruns/), etc.)

Comment: Does the log off warning message look something [like this](http://www.sevenforums.com/system-security/275578-you-about-logged-off-windows-will-shut-down-1-minute.html)?

Comment: I assume to open the "go pro footage" folder you double click it. Try right clicking then checking the properties to make sure it's actually a folder, and not a file displaying a folder icon.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds very much like a joke by a friend(?). The simplest way to check if the Go Pro folder is a real folder is to right-click the icon and select "Properties" at the end of the context menu. This should tell you a lot.

Comment: So my go pro folder was actually a fake folder that would do that pop up and make the computer shut down. I found the original folder stuck in another folder with all my videos. Problem fixed. Thanks all for the input!!!

Comment: Yeah, many of us have been the victim of this. :-)

Comment: @David since you tried to open the "folder" your computer is probably still infected. I'd recommend you do a full system scan for malware using Malwarebytes Anti-Malware and Hitman Pro. Additionally also perform a boot time virus scan to make sure your computer is rid of all malware components.